# To show infimum of set is 0

Tags: real-analysis

I have read Archimedean property.

> The exercise has question to find the infimum of set $A = \{1/n: n \in \mathbb N\}$.

Intuitively I see infimum to be $0$. But I need hint to prove this using Archimedean property.

Thanks.

Comment: The Archimedean axiom is that given any $\epsilon>0$ you can find $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{n}<\epsilon$. That shows directly that no real number $\epsilon>0$ can be a lower bound for the set $A$. On the other hand it is obvious that $0$ is a lower bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\epsilon >0$ For the Archimedean property, there exist $N \in \mathbb{N}$, such that $N\epsilon>1 $, so $\frac{1}{N}< \epsilon$